# bootstrapped estimate of the sample mean variance

Tags: r, bootstrap

I am trying to fresh my memory in bootstrapping by using the following simple example, as many bootstrap learning materials use too complex models making it hard to see the essential elements of bootstrapping.

Take $n$ samples of normal random variables $(x_1, \dotsc, x_n)$ with i.i.d $\mathcal{Normal}(0, 1)$, where $i = 1,\dotsc,n$. The sample mean is $\mu = (x_1 + \dotsm + x_n)/n$ and its variance is $\textrm{var}(\mu) = 1/n$.

https://online.stat.psu.edu/stat414/node/167/

In reality, I don't know $\textrm{var}(\mu)$ is $1/n$ as I don't know what is the distribution of $x_i$. That is the whole point of using boostrapping.

Now I use bootstrap to estimate $\textrm{var}(\mu)$ by computing the variance of the means of bootstrapped samples from the vector `x`.

```
R> n=100
R> x=rnorm(n)
R> var(
+   replicate(
+     100
+     , (function() {
+       mean(sample(x, replace=T))
+ })()  
+     ))
[1] 0.01069053
```

Is this the correct way to estimate var(mu)?

When I repeat the computation of the above estimate many times, I got a mean of the estimate which has a consistent bias (in this case it is biased up, i.e., 0.01114789 vs 1/n=1/100=0.01). Is this bias always expected?

```
R> mean(
+   replicate(
+     100
+     , var(
+       replicate(
+         100
+         , (function() {
+           mean(sample(x, replace=T))
+ })()
+         ))
+     )
+   )
[1] 0.01114789
```

How to estimate this bias? Do another level of bootstrapping?

Comment: Are you trying to find the standard error of the (sample) mean?

Comment: Yes. Use it an example to make sure I understand how bootstrapping works for this simple case.

Comment: What is the variance of the data? If you simulate data with a variance below $0.01$, do you get results with that same bias up?

Comment: The last number is 0.01114789 which is greater than .01. So the bias is 0.01114789 - .01.

Comment: What do you mean by the last number? It will help immensely if you explain your code in an edit to your original post.

Comment: Much more explanation is needed.  For instance, it isn't evident what sense it makes sense to compare your "last number" to 0.01: what does that correspond to?  Certainly not to the $1/n$ in the question, *because you are not replicating the original dataset:* you are analyzing one unique dataset `x`. There appear to be answerable statistical questions here, but currently you require your readers to parse your code in order to guess what you wish to do.

Comment: The whole point of boostrapping is you just have one dataset. Then you use this one dataset to estimate the distribution from which this dataset comes from by bootstrapping from this dataset. What is the problem with having just a single `x`?